# How can we prove, in three different ways, that the following set is compact?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that the sets J,K ⊆ ℝ are both nonempty and compact. Rigorously prove that the set $A= \{x+y: x\in J, y\in K\}$ is also compact.

This is my attempted work:

As  $|x|<M_1,|y|<M_2⇒|x+y|≤|x|+|y|<M_1+M_2$ so A is bounded.

Suppose there is a converging sequence $A\in z_n→z$. We know that $z_n=x_n+y_n$, both
sequences are bounded so  $\exists x_{n_k}→x \in J ,y_{n_k}$ is also bounded so  $\exists y_{n_{k_l}}→y\in K$ . Thus $z_{n_{k_l}}→x+y\in A$ , but $z_{n_{k_l}}→z\implies z=x+y\in A$

So A is closed.

Below should be the complete work: please let me know if it is correct and rigorous, or if some other alternative proof has been left out:

Proving the above statement using three approaches:

1. **Sequential Compactness:**

Sequential compactness states that a set is compact if every sequence in the set has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in the set.

Consider a sequence a_n in A.

Since A= {x+y: x ∈ J, y ∈ K}, we can write a_n= x_n+ y_n

where x_n ∈ J and y_n ∈ K.

Since J is compact, there exists a subsequence  x_nk of  x_n that converges to a limit x in J.

Similarly, since K is compact, there exists a subsequence y_nk_l of y_nk that converges to a limit y in K.

Therefore, the sequence a_n_k_l=x_n_k_l + y_n_k_l  is a subsequence of a_n that converges to x+y which is in A.
Hence, A is sequentially compact.

2. **Heine-Borel Theorem**:

The Heine-Borel theorem states that a subset of ℝ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

*Boundedness*:

Since J and K are both compact, they are bounded.

So, there exist real numbers M and N such that  | x | ≤ M for all  x in J and | y | ≤ N for all y in K.

For any a in A,

we have a=x+y for some x in J and y in K.

Therefore, |a|= |x+y| ≤ |x| + |y| ≤ M+N

So, A is bounded.

*Closedness*:

The sum of two closed sets is closed. Since compact sets in ℝ are closed, both J and K are closed.

Therefore, A is also closed.

Since A is both bounded and closed, by the Heine-Borel theorem, A is compact.

**3**.

Consider any open cover (U_i)_i of J+K. Now, for each k ∈ K, J+{k} is a compact set (just the translation of a compact set, which is again compact) that is contained in J+K, so we can extract a finite subsequence of open sets of the covering (U_i)_i that covers J+{k}.

Now, using the compactness of K, we try to prove that it is enough to consider these finite coverings for a finite number of k∈K in order to cover J+K.
If k_1,...k_n is such a finite number of elements of K, we have that J+K is contained in the union of the finite coverings associated to each J+{k_i}. Since it is a finite union of finite collections of open sets, we obtain a finite covering for J+K.

Having obtained a finite collection of open sets of (U_i)_i that covers J+k, we have proved that J+K is compact in a third way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This looks good. Do you know the definition of covering compactness or sequential compactness?

Comment: Yes, it’s in by book. How can we use these here?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ covering compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent. Hence you just call it compactness here. Therefore proving by definition that $A$ is covering/sequential compact also gives you a rigorous proof. I mean that would be two alternatives to your proof.

Comment: Would you mind showing how you do one of these alternatives?

Comment: the sum must be bounded and closed

Answer (score 0):

Consider any open cover $(U_i)_i$ of $J+K.$ Now, for each $k \in K$, the sets $J+\{k\}$ is a compact set (just the traslation of a compact set, which is again compact) that is contained in $J+K,$ so you can extract a finite subsequence of open sets of the covering $(U_i)_i$ that covers $J+\{k\}.$ Now, using the compactness of $K$, try to prove that it is enough to consider these finite coverings for a $\textit{finite}$ number of $k \in K$ in order to cover $J+K,$ and you are done! You obtained a finite collection of open sets of $(U_i)_i$ that covers $J+k$, so you have proved that $J+K$ is compact in a second way.

By the way, your proof is correct! You can use the argument of closedness to also prove that you can extract a convergence subsequence of any sequence in J+K, which will give you the third way to prove the compactness.

Comment: How do you go from " using the compactness of K, try to prove that it is enough to consider these finite coverings for a finite number of k∈K in order to cover J+K…" to " you obtained a finite collection of open sets…" ?

Comment: If $k_1,...k_n$ is such a finite number of elements of K, you have that J+K is contained in the union of the finite coverings associated to each $J+\{k_i\}$. Since it is a finite union of finite collections of open sets, you obtain a finite covering for $J+K$.

Comment: I’ve edited my initial post and included all three approaches. Please kindly let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Yes it seems nice, but I think you should fill the gap for the last proof!